# SQL: What does NULL as ColumnName imply

Tags: sql, column-alias

I understand that `AS` is used to create an alias. Therefore, it makes sense to have one long name aliased as a shorter one. However, I am seeing a `SQL` query `NULL as ColumnName`
What does this imply?

```
SELECT *, NULL as aColumn
```

Comment: can you show the whole query or something more...  like `select '1' as numbering from tablename`

Comment: @sac added query as it stands

Comment: I think LittleBobbyTables's answer is right, it is a *NULL* value for aColumn for all rows...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Aliasing can be used in a number of ways, not just to shorten a long column name.

In this case, your example means you're returning a column that always contains `NULL`, and it's alias/column name is `aColumn`.

Aliasing can also be used when you're using computed values, such as `Column1 + Column2 AS Column3`.

Comment: I think so too ;)  As to *why* they wrote the query like that, it's anyone's guess.  As it's written, it really doesn't do anything other than return all the columns, plus an extra column called `aColumn`.  Without seeing any surrounding code or business processes, it's hard to guess what the intent of the query is.

Comment: And the datatype of this column is `int`

Answer (score 4):

When unioning or joining datasets using a 'Null AS [ColumnA] is a quick way to make sure create a complete dataset that can then be updated later and a new column does not need to be created in any of the source tables.

Answer (score 3):

Query result can have a new column that has all NULL values. In SQL Server we can do it like this

```
SELECT *, CAST(NULL AS <data-type>) AS as aColumn
```

e.g.

```
SELECT *, CAST(NULL AS BIGINT) AS as aColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

In the statement result we have a column that has all NULL values. We can refer to that column using alias.

In your case the query selects all records from table, and each result record has additional column containing only NULL values. If we want to refer to this result set and to additional column in other place in the future, we should use alias.

Answer (score 1):

It means that `"aColumn"` has only Null values. This column could be updated with actual values later but it's an empty one when selected.

---I'm not sure if you know about SSIS, but this mechanism is useful with SSIS to add variable value to the "empty" column.

Comment: just to be sure, SSIS means: SQL Server Integration Services ?

Comment: Yes. A query as you posted could work as source table, then variable set in SSIS could be used to provide values for the empty column.

Answer (score 1):

When using SELECT you can pass a value to the column directly.
So something like :

```
SELECT ID, Name, 'None' AS Hobbies, 0 AS NumberOfPets, NULL AS Picture, '' AS Adress
```

Is valid.

It can be used to format nicely a query output when using UNION/UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

How about without using the the as 
SELECT ID
, Name
, 'None' AS Hobbies
, 0 AS NumberOfPets
, NULL Picture

Answer (score 0):

Usually adding NULL as [Column] name at the end of a select all is used when inserting into another table a calculated column based on the table you have just selected.

```
UPDATE #TempTable SET aColumn = Column1 + Column2 WHERE ...
```

Then exporting or saving the results to another table.